# How do we write catalysis when writing equations?

Tags: support, formatting

Many reactions are invoked/sped up by presence of certain chemical substance. This is called [catalysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalyser).

As far as I know, catalyst is then written above the arrow of the reaction. The same is also used when reaction requires certain temperature or pressure. How do I write this properly using Tex?

So far,  was using this approach:

$$\ce{2NaHCO3 →300°C→ Na2CO3 + H2O + CO2}$$

I don't really like it.

Comment: I just noticed you use unicode `→` to set the arrows. There are a variety of possibilities to do that with [mhchem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mhchem) which is implemented in MathJax. For example $\ce{->}$ `$\ce{->}$`; $\ce{<->}$ `$\ce{<->}$`;  $\ce{<=>}$ `$\ce{<=>}$`,  $\ce{<<=>}$ `$\ce{<<=>}$` ... Use the [sandbox](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/111/formatting-sandbox-please-test-stuff-here) to experiment :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `[...]` right after the arrow. Use it again if you want to add more text below the arrow.
$$\ce{Pb ->[\rm magic][\Delta] Au}$$

If you want to include chemical formulas you have to include them in `[\ce{...}]`$$\ce{Pb ->[\mathrm{magic}~\ce{H2O}][\Delta] Au}$$

Use `T[...]` right after the arrow to add descriptive text. If you want to add something below the equation, this will also be set as text, you have to escape with `$...$` again if you want to add math or chemistry `$\ce{...}$`.
$$\ce{Pb ->T[magic water with the eye of Newt][$\Delta$] Au}$$

Comment: I added some more example, I hope you don't mind ;)

Comment: I also noticed you used a TeX style command `\rm`, while here this does not really matter, but in a LaTeX document this might destroy your markup. Use `{\rmfamily ...}, \textrm{}, \mathrm{}` instead.

Comment: @Martin I know, I was just lazy here :)